# Ansible Playbook error in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible, yum

I've written a simple playbook to install httpd. Here is my playbook:

```
    ---
    - name: install httpd
      hosts: localhost
      become: root
      vars:
       inputvariable: "{{lookup('file','/home/ec2-user/inputfile.json')}}"
     tasks:
       - yum:
          name:  "{{item.packagename}}"
          state: "{{item.state}}"
        with_items: '{{ inputvariable.resources}}'
```

Here is my input file:

```
    {
     "resources":[
     {
      "packagename": "httpd",
      "state": "present"
     }
   ]
 }
```

The problem is when I execute the playbook with the following command from the console it executes successfully.

```
     ansible-playbook -vvv -C -e "ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python" apacheplaybook.yml
```

But when executed in Jenkins It shows the following error:

> "msg": "python2 bindings for rpm are needed for this module. python2 yum module is needed for this  module"}

This is how I run the jenkins project:
[image]

I'm running Jenkins as ec2-user and I have changed the owner ship of `/var/lib/jenkins` & `/var/log/jenkins` & `/var/cache/jenkins` to ec2-user and wheel group. Problem is with Jenkins as from console it executes successfully with this command.

Comment: you are running the playbook with jenkins's ansible plugin as well. try to remove this plugin and run the playbook for shell executer

Comment: @ArbabNazar Well that failed miserably as jenkins was unable to find the playbook itself even after mentioning the path of the playbook in the "ansible-playbook" command. Prior to this it successfully obtained the playbook and assigned the input from the i/p file too before showing the python module error

Comment: may be you can add the `cd ${WORKSPACE}/` above the `ansible-playbook` command so that it can find the playbook.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that jenkins doesn't have access the python2 bindings because it has python3 as its default therefore the yum task cannot execute.

if you switched to:

```
- name: install httpd
  package: pkg={{item}} state=installed
  with_items:
    - packagenamehere
```

Perhaps you have access on the cli to python2 but not in jenkins (I am assuming you are executing on cli on the same server jenkins is)